# Automorphisms of Grothendieck rings coming from fusion categories

Tags: fusion-categories

The Grothendieck ring $\mathcal K_0(\mathcal C)$ of a fusion category $\mathcal C$ is a unital based ring in the sense of [math/0111139v1](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0111139) with basis $B$ and involution $*$. Basis elements correspond to isomorphism classes of simple objects wixth structure constants $N_{XY}^Z=dim(\mathcal C_1(X\otimes Y,Z))$. A simple object $X$ of $\mathcal C$ is said to be self-dual if $X^*\cong X$. Automorphisms $\phi$ of $Aut(\mathcal K_0(\mathcal C))$ are given by permutations on basis elements which fix $1$ and satisfy $$N_{XY}^Z=N_{\phi(X)\phi(Y)}^{\phi(Z)}$$.

> **Question**: Let $\mathcal K_0(\mathcal C)$ be the Grothendieck ring of a fusion category with at least one pair $(X,Y)$ of non-self dual objects. When (if ever) is $Aut(\mathcal K_0(\mathcal C))$ trivial?

The first thing that should be true is $\mathcal K_0(\mathcal C)$ is non-commutative. If it were, $*$ becomes an automorphism which has to be non-trivial since it sends $X$ to $Y$. I believe this also means that $\mathcal C$ cannot be pointed, i.e. $\mathcal K_0(\mathcal C)\cong \mathbb Z[G]$ for some finite group $G$, since $\mathbb Z[G]$ should inherit its automorphism group from $G$ and $Inn(G)\cong G/Z(G)$.

Beyond that I am less sure. I have not yet managed to convince myself that if $\mathcal C$ has a non-trivial or $\mathbb Z_2$ pointed subcategory that there must be a non-trivial automorphism inherited from above, but that seems reasonable.

Since my conditions require that $\mathcal K_0(\mathcal C)$ be non-commutative, examples are sparse. I've checked that the non-commutative Grothendieck rings $H_6$ coming from the Haagerup subfactor (Table 1 in [1102.2631v2](http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.2631)), $N-N$ coming from the extended Haagerup subfactor (Figure 8 of [0909.4099](http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.4099)), and $AH_2$ coming from the Asaeda-Haagerup subfactor (Table 2 of [12.02.4396](http://arxiv.org/abs/1202.4396)) all have non-trivial automorphisms: $\alpha\leftrightarrow \alpha^2$ together with $\alpha \xi\leftrightarrow \alpha^2\xi$, $P\leftrightarrow Q$ together with $A\leftrightarrow B$, and conjugation by $\alpha$ as examples in the notation for each respectively.